# How to pause setTimeout when leaving the window with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a few setTimeout functions in my project each with a setInterval.

From what I've experienced setInterval stops when I'm leaving the window, however, setTimeout does not stop counting the seconds.

Is it possible to pause the timer of the setTimeout when someone leaves the current window (switches over to another) and continue it when he returns? If yes, how?

Here's the code I've managed to create that represents my problem:

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var banner2 = $("#banner-message2")
var banner3 = $("#banner-message3")
var num = 0;
var num2 = 0;
var num3 = 0;

var i1 = setInterval(function() {
 num++;
  $(banner).text(num);
  if (num >= 100)
  {
   clearInterval(i1);
  }
}, 50);

setTimeout(function()
{
 var i2 = setInterval(function() {
    num2++;
    $(banner2).text(num2);
    if (num2 >= 100)
    {
      clearInterval(i2);
    }
  }, 50);
}, 5500);

setTimeout(function()
{
 var i3 = setInterval(function() {
    num3++;
    $(banner3).text(num3);
    if (num3 >= 100)
    {
      clearInterval(i3);
    }
  }, 50);
}, 11000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}


#banner-message2 {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}


#banner-message3 {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  0
</div>

<div id="banner-message2">
  0
</div>

<div id="banner-message3">
  0
</div>
```

Comment: Interval timers don't stop when the window/tab loses focus. They slow down, but they don't stop.

Comment: You need to listen for a window leave event (`document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', ...)`), then use `clearTimeout` or `clearInterval`

Comment: Use the [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to know when your page is visible or not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus why not? I've literally done this in the past - JS would be running some functionality only when a tab is active and not otherwise.

Comment: @VLAZ Because there is no mechanism to "pause" a timer. You can stop one and then start a new one, but not pause one. And when you start that new one, there's no way to know how much time was left on the old one.

Comment: @ScottMarcus and pause is actually a stop/start toggle in many cases. So are you saying it's not possible to stop/start but to stop/start?

Comment: That's rather pedantic. I'd think any normal interpretation of what the question is asking would effectively equate "pausing" to "stopping and starting". Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's not pedantic. I think a "normal" interpretation of *pausing* a timer means that when you restart it, the clock begins at where it left off. If a timer had already counted to, say 42 seconds of a 60 second count, you wouldn't be able to know that there was 18 seconds left on the timer so that when you started the new one, that's how much time to start with.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by *it's not possible to stop/start but to stop/start*

Comment: @ScottMarcus it's what you said. Only the first "start/stop" you called by it's (often) synonym - "pause". And I really don't know why you think it's completely impossible to know when something started and when it was stopped, either. As if we haven't been using timestamps to mark these since forever. So, even if you wanted a "pause" to keep the elapsed time, you can do it. Sure, it's not an in-built option but saying it's "impossible" is very much untrue.

Comment: @VLAZ You're talking about building your own timer. That's not what the question was. The question was can you pause a `setTimeout()`. Since that API feeds into the browser itself, how do you propose to get the amount of time remaining from that API?

Comment: @ScottMarcus not from that API but you simply drop a timestamp when `setTimeout` is called and another one when you call `clearTimeout`. Work out how much time has elapsed and account for it when re-starting. So you can have a "pause" functionality using `setTimeout`. Let's review, you stated it's absolutely impossible, when shown you can start/stop, you moved the goalposts to "but you can't save the remaining time", when I said you can, you moved goalposts again to "but not from the API". Is there going to be another goalpost move?

Comment: @VLAZ *So you can have a "pause" functionality using setTimeout* <-- That's not at all true. What you've done is created your own timings and that's not how I read the question. **`setTimeout()` has no capability for pause. That's a fact** and that's what I was responding to. Saying that you can build your own timings and therefore you can pause `setTimeout()` is incorrect. You've been moving the goal posts. I have consistently been talking about pausing `setTimeout()` and nothing else.

Comment: **Question:** *Is it possible to pause the timer of the setTimeout when someone leaves the current window* **Answer:** No. `setTimeout()` has no such capability. If the question had been *"Can I build my own timings so that I can pick up a timing when the user comes back to my page?"*, the answer would be "Yes", but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus then post your answer that says "What you want to do is not possible"

Comment: @VLAZ That's not appropriate for an "answer" on Stack Overflow, hence my very simple and clear comment. **Conversely, you should post an answer showing how you believe that it is.**

Comment: @ScottMarcus but it *is* - if the only answer is "it's not possible", then it's the only answer. It can only be inappropriate if it's wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can watch for when a tab loses focus by using the event listener `visibilitychange`. When the visibility changes, you can use `document.hidden` to see if the document is hidden. If it is you can then clear the timeout. When it regains focus, you can call `setTimeout` to resume function.

```
let myTimeout = null

function timeoutfunction() { 
  console.log('timeout called')
  myTimeout = setTimeout(timeoutfunction, 1000)
}

function onVisibilityChanged() {
  if (document.hidden || document.mozHidden || document.webkitHidden || document.msHidden) {
    // The tab has lost focus
    clearTimeout(myTimeout)
  } else {
    // The tab has gained focus
    myTimeout = setTimeout(timeoutfunction, 1000)
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged, false);
document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged, false);
document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it would actually reset the timer of the setTimeout function, wouldn't it? I'd need a solution that's pausing the timeout and then resuming once the user returns. Is that even possible? If yes, can you please show it how?

Comment: You can't pause a function halfway through.

Comment: You may be able to use `yield`, but I am not sure on that