# Tracking User Active Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way I can track the time when a user is active on my Next.js web application.
Note this is not the time between User "Sign In" and "Sign Out". I want to track the time they spent on my web application in a day. Maybe I could get it in form of array of sessions like

```js
day1: [
"(From timestamp) - (To timestamp)", 
"(From timestamp) - (To timestamp)", // starts after a gap of minimum 30 min
"(From timestamp) - (To timestamp)"
]
```

**Solutions I don't prefer:**

- Using a `setInterval` function and update "To timestamp" repeatedly after few seconds. I can't afford database writes of many users. They would be too much.
- Using interactions as source of activity. This is not relevant in my case. I have a multimedia application, it may have videos & livestreams going and we cannot count as inactivity while user doesn't interact but still watching the livestream.

Comment: you can do this by connecting users to a simple socket room outside of firebase. with firebase it can be quite difficult to do this cleanly.

Comment: You may could use the `focus` event on window, `swr` lib is doing it to re-fetch data

Comment: "I want to track the time they spent on my web application in a day" => How do you exactly define the time spent on your web application? Time between the first and last interactions with the Firebase backends? Time the browser is opened on a page of your app? etc...

Comment: my bad. interactions doesn't mean anything to me. I just want the time between they open any page of website and close that page from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would be periodically incrementing the number of seconds the user is active on your tab. I'm not sure about mixins in React but you can create one and use it on all components/pages.

```
let durationOpen = 0
setInterval(() => {
  // update any local variable or update to database
  durationOpen += 5
}, 5000)
```

It's totally upto you how frequently you wish to update it in your database. You can easily increment the number of seconds the user has been on your tab in realtime database:

```
const userRef= firebase.database().ref("users/user_id");
userRef.push({
  time: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(5) // num of seconds
});
```

If you need to stop the timeout when use changes the tab so, checkout:

[How to pause setTimeout when leaving the window with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948840/how-to-pause-settimeout-when-leaving-the-window-with-javascript)